# How much time is required to get my osm data updated

Tags: openstreetmap

I updated some roads in osm map. I updated using JOSM. But the updates are not visible in the map after 2 days. I am new to osm maps. Can anyone please tell me the possible reasons.

Comment: Check here an you can view your changesets - http://www.khtml.org/osm/v0.63/examples/changes.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, your edits will appear on the default mapnik layer on osm.org within several minutes or hours.

However, there's a few reasons why your edits haven't appeared:
- the tags that you used are incorrect; some obscurer features (for example, a power generator) don't render (appear) on the default mapnik later used on osm.org.

[This QandA](http://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/102/i-have-made-edits-but-they-dont-show-up-on-the-map) discusses these reasons and others more in-depth.